# Inserting date using yesterday/tomorrow into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm trying to insert a date into Cassandra based on the current date.

```
create table mobileTimeSeries (
deviceid text,
date date,
PRIMARY KEY(deviceid, date));

insert into mobileTimeSeries (deviceid, date) values ('test', toDate(now()));
```

That works, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like

```
insert into mobileTimeSeries (deviceid, date) values ('test', toDate(now()-1));
insert into mobileTimeSeries (deviceid, date) values ('test', toDate(now()+1));
```

I just get this error mismatched input '+' expecting ')' (... 'tablet',toDate(now()) [+]...)

Not sure if this is possible at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate date on your app and just insert it as a date instead of using now().

After [CASSANDRA-11936](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11936) in 4.0+ you can do `now() - 1d` kinda things.